# pandas : stacked bar plot from customers orders

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to do a stacked plot bar from customers order on many companies. I want to show each order as a part of the bar of each company. The issue is that I do have an uncertain number of order by company, and that the display of the plot may do my jupyter notebook crash.

Conceptually I reach my goal with the following :

```
company1   = pd.Series([10,10,10])
company2   = pd.Series([20,20])
df         = pd.DataFrame([company1, company2]).T
df.columns = ["company1", "company2"]
df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

which give me a plot : 
[image]

Now how can I apply that on my dataset ?

I try the following on a subset of my data (only 3 companies in p2) :

```
p3         = p2[["COMPANY", "TOTAL_PAID"]]
companies  = [company             for company, group in p3.groupby("COMPANY")]
series     = [group["TOTAL_PAID"] for company, group in p3.groupby("COMPANY")]
df         = pd.DataFrame(series).T
df.columns = companies
df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True, legend=False)
```

and it works :

[image]

but when I apply it on the whole file (who is still small : 15 k lines) I can wait a long long time before getting any result (indeed I wrote this whole question after launching the plot creation, and it is not displayed yet ...) , so the question are :

1. Is it a good strategy this idea of the two comprehension lists ? I thaught it was a bit suboptimal...
2. Is it normal that the display of the plot takes so long ?
3. Is it normal that jupyter may crash ?

Comment: I do not have an answer to your question but I really doubt that a stacked bar chart is the best solution here (if the data really looks like your second image suggests). I would try to calculate some numbers like heterogeneity of payments or so and use a table or so

Comment: If you are trying to plot 15000 bars, yet it's normal that it takes long. Maybe remember that a data visualization should *help*  the viewer understand the data. I highly doubt that the plot you attempt here is adding constructively to this aim.

Comment: I have to agrre, a violin plot seems more more interesting on this problem